# Comparing Huge Files using C++

Tags: c++, file, diff

I have two big text Files each having more than 10 Million lines. How can i compare the files and get different lines in the files using C++.

I have tried loading one file into memory and sorted the memory and used the binary tree logic to compare the files. It compared and gave me the result in 20 Sec. But it's consuming more memory. (The text file is around 500 MB).

I want to compare two files without consuming more memory, a Good Performance and to have minimal effects on Hard Disk.

Comment: The first step is to chose a language. The solutions will be different for C and C++.

Comment: Would a diff tool not meet your requirements? Easier than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This reminds me of "Quality, Budget, Time - pick two"

Comment: Do you mean like a diff? Just read one line of each file at a time. Otherwise the question is too vague and ambiguous. Are the files just sets of lines, meaning their ordering is unimportant? It's not clear what "different lines" mean exactly.

Comment: Do you want to know where the two files differ (basically a `diff`) or which lines are in one but not in the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a two pass method.

first pass, you read files but only store hash value and line start pos of lines, then u can compare files based on hash value, you only read the lines again for complete compare in the second pass when two lines have same hash value. this will save memory consumption and cpu time, with a bit penalty to read some lines twice.

Comment: I was suggesting the same, but then I thought that when hash are **equal** (almost ever) fetching the text could be necessary to be sure of comparison. Thus this naive strategy maybe it's not very effective. OTH diff should use something similar.

Comment: If you don't care if you make a mistake once or twice before the universe ends, simply use 128 bit hash code over the source lines. The probability that getting a bad compare for 10 million lines is (1-2^(-128))*10^7 ~~ 1-2^(-103). Seems safe enough.

Comment: @IraBaxter Well, actually I care ;) and I think a lot of people care too.